# LINQ select first item from multi layer class

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
public class IP_BankInfo
{
    public App.BankType BankType { get; set; }
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
    public List<IP_BankRows> Rows { get; set; }
}
public class IP_BankRows
{
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public List<IP_BankBindings> Bindings { get; set; }
}
public class IP_BankBindings
{
    public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedHeader { get; set; }
    public string TransactionPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to select the first `IP_BankRows`, if it contains any `Bindings`, where `TransactionPropertyName` is not empty. Here is my try:

```
var firstItem = info.Rows.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Bindings.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TransactionPropertyName)));
```

but it fails at the second condition `(n=>n.Bindings...)`. How do I need to change my statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable<T>` in this case, and that is not a boolean value. What you need to use is `.Any()`.

```
var firstItem = info.Rows.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Bindings.Any(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TransactionPropertyName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
var firstItem = info.Rows.Where(
    n => n.Bindings.Any(
        x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.TransactionPropertyName)
    )
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution. (They're usually especially discouraged on self-answers.)